# Regex to extract list of strings with nested brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of strings similar to this in js:

```
params[0][header][name[0]]
```

and I need to split them up into a list like this:

```
["params", "0", "header", "name[0]"]
```

Very easy thing to solve until you get to the nested brackets.
The best I have come up with so far is this regex:

```
'params[0][header][name[0]]'.match(/([^\[]+)|\[(.+?\]?)\]/g)
```

Which returns:

```
["params", "[0]", "[header]", "[name[0]]"]
```

that I can work with but I need an extra step to remove unneeded brackets.

My question is that, is there a regex that I can apply to the string and it returns a list without the *extra* brackets?

I could not find any solutions this on stackoverflow nor google. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Regular expressions are unable to handle recursion on their own.

Comment: I know that. My question was if I can apply a regex on the string(not list) and get a list without brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing parentheses is not something regex is built for. Actually parse it with a stack of brackets:

```js
function getBrackets(str) {
    const chunks = [];
    const openBrackets = [];
    let pushedFirst = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i ++) {
        if (str[i] == "[") {
            openBrackets.push(i);
            // for pushing the first section not enclosed in brackets
            if (!pushedFirst) {
                chunks.push(str.slice(0, i));
                pushedFirst = true;
            }
        } else if (str[i] == "]") {
            const start = openBrackets.pop();
            if (openBrackets.length == 0) {
                chunks.push(str.slice(start + 1, i));
            }
        }
    }
    return chunks;
}

console.log(getBrackets("params[0][header][name[0]]")); // ["params", "0", "header", "name[0]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution is not elegant :-(

```js
const str = "params[0][header][name[0]]"
const result = str.split(/\]\[/);

const last = result[result.length - 1];
result[result.length - 1] = last.substring(0, last.length - 1);

const first = result[0]
const idx = first.indexOf("[");
result[0] = first.substring(0, idx);
result.splice(1, 0, first.substring(idx + 1));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution, it simply breaks down your requirements and enforces them using a number of checks. It does assume that every "[" does have a matching "]". It can be streamlined further but this just separates each requirement individually instead of clumping them together when possible.

```
var x = "params[0][header][name[0]]";
var y = [];
var z = "";
var count = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i] != "[" && x[i] != "]") {
        z += x[i];
    }
    else if(x[i] == "[" && count==0){
        count += 1;
        y.push(z);
        z = "";
        
    }
    else if(x[i] == "["){
        z += x[i];
        count += 1;
    }
    else if(x[i] == "]" && count == 1){
        count -= 1;
    }
    if(x[i] == "]" && count > 1){
        count -= 1
        z+= x[i];
    }
    if(i == x.length-1){
        y.push(z);
    }
}
```